# Where the WordPress Core Translation is "actually" taking place?

Tags: translation, wordpress-version, wordpress.org

I'm a WordPress Core Bengali translator, currently translating and/or fixing existing translations of [WordPress 3.8x Bengali](http://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp/3.8.x/bn/default) in Translate.WordPress.org.

Suddenly, yesterday I got an update notification in all my `WPLANG` '`bn_BD`' sites that, a new version of WordPress Bengali for WordPress 3.9 has come, so update your system. After the update I found a bluff update, because all the previous strings those were translated, got untranslated strings now. So, it's a bogus translation at all.

As a Core translator, I jumped to the translate.wordpress.org's [WordPress Projects](http://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp), but found no such 3.9x translation project there.

I wonder, **from Where** the official language release just happened, (as v3.9 is NOT a Dev. version now, it's a released one) if there's no such project's running!?

Comment: It looks like the 3.9 tag is missing in some translations and 4.0-alpha is delivered instead, see for example discussion on https://make.wordpress.org/polyglots/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I maintain WordPress Bengali project and yesterday I pushed the 3.9 translation update from bn.wordpress.org.

You are right, there are no 3.9.x branch there so it's pretty much not clear to me as well. Here's how it works: we should always translate from the Dev version. When a new release comes, there is a SVN revision for that WordPress release. We just refer to that revision and build a language pack from the development version (trunk). So whatever it's there, its been released as the new version.

[image]